# show_transfers fields

Tags: transfer, show-transfers

I wanted to test the monero cli wallet to make transfers using a subaddress instead of the primary address because I read that this will make the transfer with an encrypted payment ID and is thus a more anonymous option.

So I made a transfer from my sub-address to my primary address just to try out what would happen. I used a small quantity. I'm trying to understand what happened by investigating the output of the `show_transfers` command.

However, I cannot make sense of what it means. In addition to my sub-address there is another field, that looks like an address, which I do not recognize. It is not of my own.

Could someone explain the output of "show_transfers" to me so that I can be sure I understand what I'm getting? Or can you refer me to where I can learn about the information provided when looking up transfers? Thank you!

I copied an example below, with changes in numbers for anonymity. What does each field mean?

```
1020393    out        -       2020-05-01 01:01:52       0.000000000000 f7c031c53cc0aa2f2e021ff44a8feadd462f2002feee6a09d254288b50f53ccf 0000000000000000 0.000101530000 894HLgLpdQSAn2j29EMcZfQ3DwaT5RkncFmRHF2GvuSDgxa2tALcL22MMXtoo5Vr2eLhxqRH5UK2X4oV7J3cPWAyTQJxCA8:0.100000000000 0 -
```

Answer (score 1):

`help show_transfers` documents all the fields.

```
help show_transfers
Command usage: 
  show_transfers [in|out|pending|failed|pool|coinbase] [index=[,,...]] [ []]

Command description: 
  Show the incoming/outgoing transfers within an optional height range.

Output format:
  In or Coinbase:    Block Number, "block"|"in",              Time, Amount,  Transaction Hash, Payment ID, Subaddress Index,                     "-", Note
  Out:               Block Number, "out",                     Time, Amount*, Transaction Hash, Payment ID, Fee, Destinations, Input addresses**, "-", Note
  Pool:                            "pool", "in",              Time, Amount,  Transaction Hash, Payment Id, Subaddress Index,                     "-", Note, Double Spend Note
  Pending or Failed:               "failed"|"pending", "out", Time, Amount*, Transaction Hash, Payment ID, Fee, Input addresses**,               "-", Note

  * Excluding change and fee.
  ** Set of address indices used as inputs in this transfer.
```

As you are showing the output for an "out", the fields are:

```
Block Number, "out", Time, Amount, Transaction Hash, Payment ID, Fee, Destinations, Input addresses, "-", Note
```

Also note, sending from a primary address, a subaddress  or an integrated address are all equally anonymous.